# Filter by AVG using Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a file "error_data.txt" as below:

```
10474   3.0 2013-05-01  7
10474   94.0    2013-05-01  3
10538   72.0    2013-05-01  15
11001   95.0    2013-05-01  248
13113   78.0    2013-05-01  18
13116   53.0    2013-05-01  4
13116   95.0    2013-05-01  1
13122   89.0    2013-05-01  2
10001   56.0    2013-05-02  7
10413   61.0    2013-05-02  6
.........
.........
```

This is what I have till now and it works fine:

```
error_data = LOAD 'error_data.txt' AS (ppapi_error_code:int, api_version:chararray, day:chararray, count:long);
filtered_data = FILTER error_data BY api_version=='61.0';                                                      
grouped_data = GROUP filtered_data BY day;                                                                     
grouped_count = FOREACH grouped_data GENERATE group AS day, SUM(filtered_data.count) AS error_count;
STORE grouped_count INTO 'out_1';
```

Now what I want to do is filter `grouped_count` for those values which have an `error_count` greater than the average.

I have obtained the average as follows:

```
grouped_count_bag = GROUP grouped_count ALL;
average = FOREACH grouped_count_bag GENERATE AVG(grouped_count.error_count);
```

When I `DUMP` it, I get the value in a tuple as `(578.9444444444445)`. I am now able to filter it with the value as

```
filtered_grouped_count = FILTER grouped_count BY (error_count>578.9444444444445);
```

but i want to do it as

```
filtered_grouped_count = FILTER grouped_count BY (error_count>average);
```

which does not seem to be allowed. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
average = FOREACH grouped_count_bag GENERATE AVG(grouped_count.error_count) AS avg;
grouped_count_average = CROSS grouped_count, average;
filtered_grouped_count = FILTER grouped_count_average BY (error_count>avg);
```

I know that CROSS seems wasteful, but as far as I know that's the only way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I can only try it out tomorrow as I don't have my VM with me at present. I'll get back to this ASAP.

Comment: @RoneyMichael you don't need a vm. Just install pig locally and try out the above. If you're on a Mac: `brew install pig`. Then just `pig -x local` with the dummy data copied from above, and the commands posted :)

Comment: Windows.. I'm not on my system; no Cygwin either. :/